# Value cannot be null. Error on opening webpage in .net

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have a web application that runs fine on a local dev server(the one that comes with ,net) but when uploaded to iis8 it comes up with a null exception. Not sure where to start.

The app is runing version 4 of the framework.

```
Value cannot be null.
```

Parameter name: type 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type]
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +10703382
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.CreateMyInstance(String username, Boolean isAuthenticated) +77
System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(String username, Boolean isAuthenticated) +256
System.Web.HttpContext.get_Profile() +113
MB.ASTechnology.UI.BasePage.InitializeCulture() +36
ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlTree(default_aspx __ctrl) +91
 ASP.default_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +44
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +48
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +4
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: check in function `MB.ASTechnology.UI.BasePage.InitializeCulture()`

Comment: Does your web server have .NET framework 4 on it?  Is your App Pool set to run under .NET 4?

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for your hints. It was a referencing issue, which needed fixing.